# Python - Raise Jenkins error

Tags: python, jenkins

I  have an script in Python and I need to raise an exception/error and stop the build with Jenkins if a problem occurs. I tried with everything:

```
return False
return 2
sys.exit(-2)
sys.exit("Error found")
assert 2
assert "Error"
raise Exception("Error found")
sys.exit()
```

No matter what Jenkins keeps building instead of stopping and notify the error.

---

Update: I just want to raise the error and stop the Jenkins build, code looks like:

```
def script(param):
    if param>5:
        #raise Error
    else:
        #Do stuff
```

Comment: do you have your whole code?

Comment: @smushi check the example

Comment: @smushi just tried, it doesn't work. The build jumps to the next step after this script exits with `sys.exit()`.

Comment: how is the build called?

Comment: It's a build with parameters, it's called by URL. I made sure the `param` is passed right. Later the script is called with `python -c "execfile('myscript.py'); script(%param%)"`